# Checkboxlist in YII AJAX filter deselecting items

Tags: yii

I have an ajaxfilter on a YII listview. When I select an item in the checkboxlist everything works properly: ajax calls vacature/index and gives 'vacature' the right ID which I handle in my controller, so this works fine. (vacature/index?vacature=13)

Now when I uncheck the same item it does exactly the same call, so it passes the id of the changed item. I only need it to not pass the id of the de-selected item and the string to be empty.

Thanks in advance!

```
echo CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('vacature/index')), 'get', array('id'=>'filter-vacature'))

echo CHtml::checkBoxList('niveau', (isset($_GET['niveau'])) ? $_GET['niveau'] : '', 
  CHtml::listData(Lov::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('wat'=>'opleiding')), 'id', 'item'),
  array('class'=>'niveau','template'=>'<span class="checkbox-columns">{input} {label}</span>', 'separator'=>'')) 


$('.niveau').change(function(){
            niveau = $('.niveau').serialize();
            $.fn.yiiListView.update(
                'ajaxListView',
                {data: niveau}
            );
        });
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I looked up my code and found that I added an empty value check. Hope it helps you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comparison to check if the string is empty, and pass the working empty value:

```
$('.niveau').change(function(){
                niveau = $('.niveau').serialize();
                if(empty(niveau))
                {
                    niveau = 'niveau%5B%5D=0';
                }

                $.fn.yiiListView.update(
                    'ajaxListView',
                    {data: niveau}
                );

            });
```